# SQL Group by to reduce duplicate records shown to user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is called to display a table to the user.  The purpose of the query is to select the top row with a where clause and then select all other records in the table that have the same ID.  When this displays to the user certain fields are all the same e.g ID, Name, Country and then there are other fields that are not repeated so all need to be displayed to the user.  My query is as follows:

```
select * from authorise where UID IN (
      select top 1 UID from authorise where  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   trained
               WHERE  authorise.resellername = trained.resellername AND
                      authorise.accountnumber = trained.accountnumber) and frequency = FrequencyLoad order by UID) AND  AccountNumber IN(
  select top 1 ACCOUNTNUMBER from authorise where  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM   trained
              WHERE  authorise.resellername = trained.resellername AND
                     authorise.accountnumber = trained.accountnumber) and frequency = FrequencyLoad order by UID)
```

The records that are in (*) are (AuthoriseID, UID, ResellerName, AccountNumber, AccountName, MISO, Match,frequency)  The records that are distinct are (AuthoriseID, UID, ResellerName, AccountNumber, AccountName, MISO)

In my view I just have normal tables to show the data.  I have the tables split up so on one table I should only have 1 row for AuthoriseID, UID, ResellerName, AccountNumber, AccountName, MISO and on the second table I would have as many records as needed for Match,frequency.

I was trying to use `group by` and `distinct` but I couldn't get it working.

EDIT:

```
 Authorise Table:
|AuthoriseID, UID, ResellerName, AccountNumber, AccountName, MISO, Match, Freq|
[10, 19, 'ITSystemsLtd', 23, 'ITSystems', 'AU', 'ITSystems', 1]
[11, 19, 'ITSystemsLtd', 23, 'ITSystems', 'AU', 'IT', 100]
[12, 19, 'ITSystemsLtd', 23, 'ITSystems', 'AU', 'Systems', 89]
```

The above shows how the table look in the database and also what is shown when I run the above query.  I have two table in my view and I want the data to appear like below:

```
      [Table 1]                               
[19, 'ITSystemsLtd', 23, 'ITSystems', 'AU']

      [Table 2]
   ['ITSystems', 1]
   [ 'IT', 100]
   ['Systems', 89]
```

I dont want the some of the data duplicated as there is not need to show it several times to the user.

My view code is as follows :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorise", "Home"))
{
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
        <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar1">
            <table style="width:100%" class="table">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th align="center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UID)
                        </th>
                        <th align="center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ResellerName)
                        </th>

                        <th align="center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
                        </th>
                        <th align="center">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.AccountName)
                        </th>

                        <th align="center">
                            Accept/Reject
                        </th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>


                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.AuthoriseID)

                    <tr>

                        <td style="width:5%;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.UID)

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:21%;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.ResellerName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => 
item.ResellerName)

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:10%;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.AccountNumber)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => 
item.AccountNumber)

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:22%;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.AccountName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.AccountName)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:12%;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Accept", "Accept", "Home", 
new { item.AuthoriseID }, null) ||
                                @Html.ActionLink("Reject", "Reject", "Home", 
new { item.AuthoriseID }, null)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }


            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

  <div class="col-xs-3">
  @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MISO)
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.MISO, new { @readonly = "readonly", 
@class = "textBoxfreq" })
}

</div>



  @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateFrequency", "Home"))
{
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.PercentageMatch)
                </th>
                <th align="center">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Frequency)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
          @foreach (var item in Model)
          {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.AuthoriseID)
            <tr>
                <td style="width:60%;">

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PercentageMatch)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PercentageMatch)
                </td>
                <td style="width:40%;">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Frequency)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Frequency)

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

}

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: This looks like more an application problem to be solved than a query. You should be asking how to handle the data on your application view rather than in the query. Assuming the query is showing the right results.

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos yes possibly.  I think possibly removing the foreach in the first table might work

Comment: @TheImpaler I have added example data and more code.  But as Jorge said it is possibly something I need to do with the applicationd rather than the query

Answer (score 0):

Your data modelling seems suboptimal here. You should have two tables in the db, one that has:

```
  [Table 1]                               
  [19, 'ITSystemsLtd', 23, 'ITSystems', 'AU']
```

And one that has:

```
  [Table 2]
  [19, 'ITSystems', 1]
  [19, 'IT', 100]
  [19, 'Systems', 89]
```

As it is, in the application you will have to do something like:

```
DbContext.Authorise.Select(a=> new { a.UID, a.ResellerName, a.AccountNumber, a.AccountName } ).Distinct();
```

Or perhaps create some views in the db that mimic a master detail relationship